# PHP pdo echo results into table

Tags: php, html, mysql, function, pdo

I have a simple `SELECT` function, and I would like to echo the results into a **table**.

So far I am able to display the results in a linear fashion but not tabular.

Whenever I `echo <tr>` (see code below) it seems like it's ignored. 
What am I doing wrong?

My code so far is;

**function.php**

```
class crud {
    public function lastLogin() {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE userId=:userId");
        $stmt->bindparam(":userId", $_SESSION['user_session']);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>'.$row['lastLogin'].'</tr>'; // <- this line 
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Nothing here';
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**user.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php $crud->lastLogin(); ?>
</div>
```

Just to confirm, using the code above **does display the data** - just not in a table like I want. It's displayed in the following format;

```
2016-03-07 17:09:382016-03-08 09:12:082016-03-08 09:13:342016-03-08 09:15:022016-03-08 09:15:342016-03-08 11:42:33
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"Whenever I add <table>, <tr> or <td> it seems like they are ignored. What am I doing wrong?"* - Show us how you're using it then.

Comment: `database connection` is missing in your class!!

Comment: And I'm not sure `bindParam` is equal to `bindparam` in pdo

Comment: You `return true` form your function that's the reason you echo nothing . Instead you need to return `$row['lastLogin']`

Comment: this is an example of table syntax `<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">123</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments:

This is an example of table syntax

```
<table border="1" width="100%"> 
   <tr> 
<td width="100%">ABC</td> 
   </tr> <tr> 
<td width="100%">123</td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

And what you ended up using:

```
echo '<table><tr><td>'.$row['lastLogin'].'</td></tr></table>';
```